# TestNG: Getting java.lang.ClassCastException when the test case fails in Extent report

Tags: java, selenium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Getting java.lang.ClassCastException when the test case fails in Extent report.
I have one TestListener class which have implementation of onpass, onfailure, onskipp methods declaration in one package and have Test class in one package and Webdriver is declared under the base class of third package, it is done for better readability.

Now whenever a test case fails, the control goes to the onfailure, there we have implemented screenshots ability and that is where my code fails.

The onfailure method-

```
 public void onTestFailure(ITestResult iTestResult) {
    System.out.println("I am in onTestFailure method " +  getTestMethodName(iTestResult) + " failed");

    //Get driver from BaseTest and assign to local webdriver variable.
    Object testClass = iTestResult.getInstance();

    WebDriver webDriver = ((BaseClass) testClass).getDriver();

    //Take base64Screenshot screenshot.
    String base64Screenshot = "data:image/png;base64,"+((TakesScreenshot)webDriver).
          getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);


    //Extentreports log and screenshot operations for failed tests.
    ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.FAIL,"Test case failed",
           ExtentTestManager.getTest().addBase64ScreenShot(base64Screenshot));
    //ExtentTestManager.getTest().log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test case failed as:"+iTestResult.getThrowable());
}
```

The base class:

```
 public WebDriver getDriver()
 {
if (driver == null)
{
 System.setProperty("webdriver path here"); 
  driver= new ChromeDriver();
  return driver;
}
else
{
  return driver;
}
}
```

The error logs-

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: VWAutomationTest.TestVWLoginPage cannot be cast to Utility.BaseClass
at Listeners.TestListener.onTestFailure(TestListener.java:77)
at org.testng.internal.TestListenerHelper.runTestListeners(TestListenerHelper.java:67)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1388)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1041)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: The code you posted seems woefully unhelpfull in solving your problem. Is testClass expected to be VWAutomationTest.TestVWLoginPage? (which the error says its passed there), if so - is it sub of BaseClass at all? Thats what failed cast is pointing towards.

Comment: VWAutomationTest is the package and under that I have my Test class where in I have my tests, Baseclass is the class where I have my driver intiallized as shown in the code attached, it is in another package called Util, I hope this is helpful,

Comment: Are you extending the Baseclass? if so then change the code as WebDriver webDriver = getDriver(); try this once

Comment: that would work but would not give the screenshot of current instance and the screenshot would not  capture the exact screen of failure. Object testClass = iTestResult.getInstance();

    WebDriver webDriver = ((BaseClass) testClass).getDriver();

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer,

The mistake which I was doing was that I was not extending the Baseclass in my Test classes and in Testlistener as well as VWAutomationTest.TestVWLoginpage, I was calling object of baseclass and thus I was getting error.
To make it working I just extented the baseclass i.e

```
public class TestVWLoginPage extends Utility.BaseClass
```

Everything else remains the same.